# PayPal Subscription Cancellation from Merchant Website

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing, cancellation

we have a paypal payment system integrated into our website so people can register and choose a subscription. The subscription part works fine as the payment goes through and the IPN hits our website and updates our systems. Now we want users to be able to cancel their subscription from within our website so we have a custom cancellation button which when clients click, should send a request to paypal and cancel their subscription. We managed to get this going on sandbox test system however since we have brought the system into live testing we can not get the cancellation feature to work. So currently when the user clicks on cancel button, i think paypal is not being notified and hence no IPN received from PayPal.

Do you know what all info we need in order to cancel the subscription from our website. I know there is a way where users can log into paypal and cancel their subscription or we can log into our paypal and cancel their subscription but we want it to work from our website.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have it working on the sandbox but not live, what exactly is going wrong when you try it live?

I'm actually a little confused by that, because my initial answer was going to be that you can't kill subscriptions via the API unless you're using Recurring Payments.  Standard subscriptions aren't accessible via the API.

If you're saying you're doing that in the sandbox, though, then there must be something I'm unaware of..??

On that note, I know the PayPal system pretty well, so I'm thinking maybe you did Recurring Payments on the sandbox, but live you're using Standard Subscriptions..??  If that's accurate then you'll need to move to recurring payments instead of standard subscriptions on the live site.